# How to align bar labels on the right in barh plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Example Code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('white')


s = pd.Series({'John': 7, 'Amy': 4, 'Elizabeth': 4, 'James': 4, 'Roy': 2})
color1 = ['orange', 'grey', 'grey','grey','grey']

ax1 = s.plot(kind='barh', color=color1, figsize=(6, 3), width=.8)
ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax1.bar_label(ax1.containers[0], labels=s.index, padding=-60, color='white',
             fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
ax1.bar_label(ax1.containers[0], padding=10, color='black',
             fontsize=8, fmt='{:.0f} times'.format, fontweight='bold')
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])
sns.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
```

How can I align the bar labels on the right side of the bar in the plot?

[image]

I am looking for a way to fix this using any of the following libraries: pandas, seaborn, or matplotlib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Edit:**

You can patch `Text` manually to change the horizontal alignment and get a better result:

```
labels = ax1.bar_label(ax1.containers[0], labels=s.index, padding=-5, 
                       color='white', fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
for label in labels:
    label.set_ha('right')
```

Output:

[image]

---

### **Old answer:**

You can use `annotate` to more precisely control what you want or use `str.rjust` to get labels of the same width. However, since you are not using a monospaced font, the result is approximate:

```
zlabels = s.index.str.rjust(s.index.str.len().max())
ax1.bar_label(ax1.containers[0], labels=zlabels, padding=-65, color='white',
             fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
```

Output:

[image]